# Read/Write Xml elements and contents to listBox object

Tags: c#, xml, forms

This is an Xml file I would like to load and get the contents in the elements (without the tags) to read what is assigned to LogRecord to add to listHoursLog listBox. Now, all I want is what is written below in LogRecord="2/28/2014 8:31 PM to 12:00 AM Total Time: 00:00:01" to be the exact same way without parsing into elements etc. just as is to listHoursLog as a string so I may work with it further. Foreach LogRecord element I need them all to load into the listBox on their own separate lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--Save Log from previous use.-->
    <!--fName lName| 2/28/2014 @ 8:31 PM-->
    <root>
      <LogRecord LogRecord="2/28/2014 8:31 PM to 12:00 AM Total Time: 00:00:01" />
    </root>
```

Some code I have been trying to put together from what I found on the internet. I keep finding code that does not read the internal element contents but the elements themselves which is useless for what I need...

```
   var logList = XDocument.Load(XMLConfigFile).Root.Elements(); //XmlConfigFile is the source of the Xml data
      var contents= from element in logList.Descendants("element")
                                  select new {
                                      attribute = element.Attribute("LogRecord").Value       //Display contents of element <LogRecord>
                              };

                        listHoursLog.Items.Add(contents);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
var logList = XDocument.Load(XMLConfigFile).Root.Elements(); //XmlConfigFile is the source of the Xml data
var contents= from element in logList
              select (string)element.Attribute("LogRecord");
foreach(var content in contents)
{
    listHoursLog.Items.Add(content);
}
```

Comment: updated my answer to select `string` instead of anonymous object (`new { .. }`)

Comment: prints this exactly when I use this code,  system.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectIterator'[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,<>f_Anonymous Type 0'1[System.String]]...... not the content in the element

Comment: check updated answer. We need to add each item in `contents` to listbox using `foreach`. btw, what platform is your application, ASP.NET, winform, WPF, etc?

Comment: It is in C#, windows form app